# Cython: Pass by Reference

Tags: python, c++, pass-by-reference, cython

### Problem

I would like to pass a vector by reference to a function in Cython.

```py
cdef extern from "MyClass.h" namespace "MyClass":
    void MyClass_doStuff "MyClass::doStuff"(vector[double]& input) except +

cdef class MyClass:

...

@staticmethod
def doStuff(vector[double]& input):
    MyClass_doStuff(input)
```

### Question

The above code doesn't throw an error during compilation but it's also not working. `input` is simply unchanged after the method.
I have also tried the recommendation [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720982/cython-c-passing-by-reference) but in this case the `cdef`-function won't be accessible from Python ("unknown member doStuff...").

Is passing by reference possible and, if so, how to do it properly?

### Edit

This is not a duplicate of [cython-c-passing-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720982/cython-c-passing-by-reference) as I refer to the question in the section above. The proposed solution does not accomplish my goal of having a **python** function taking a parameter by reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cython & C++: passing by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720982/cython-c-passing-by-reference)

Comment: How are you planning on constructing a `vector<double>` in Python?  Because that's the only thing you're allowed to call that function with...

Comment: How do you expect to pass in a vector from python code?

Comment: Cython defines a cpp vector class to make use of. On the python level a list will work fine. See [vector.pxd](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**

The trouble, as Kevin and jepio say in the comments to your question, is how you handle the vector in Python. Cython does define a cpp vector class, which is automatically converted to/from a list at the boundary to Cython code.

The trouble is that conversion step: when your function is called:

```
def doStuff(vector[double]& input):
    MyClass_doStuff(input)
```

is transformed to something close to

```
def doStuff(list input):
    vector[double] v= some_cython_function_to_make_a_vector_from_a_list(input)
    MyClass_doStuff(input)
    # nothing to copy the vector back into the list
```

**The answer(s)**

I think you have two options. The first would be to write the process out in full (i.e. do two manual copies):

```
def doStuff(list input):
  cdef vector[double] v = input
  MyClass_doStuff(v)
  input[:] = v
```

This will be slow for large vectors, but works for me (my test function is `v.push_back(10.0)`):

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> doStuff(l)
>>> l
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 10.0]
```

The second option is to define your own wrapper class that directly contains a `vector[double]`

```
cdef class WrappedVector:
  cdef vector[double] v
  # note the absence of:
  #   automatically defined type conversions (e.g. from list)
  #   operators to change v (e.g. [])
  #   etc.
  # you're going to have to write these yourself!
```

and then write

```
def doStuff(WrappedVector input):
  MyClass_doStuff(input.v)
```