# Removing an element from std:vector in Cython

Tags: python, c++, vector, cython

From Cython I'm using C++'s `std:vector` and I need to remove an element. For my exact use case all of the vectors are of type `int`. I thought that the cleanest way to do this would be to use `std:remove` and vector's `erase` method. For some reason the following code is not removing the elements as expected:

```
# distutils: language=c++
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
     iter std_remove "std::remove" [iter, T](iter first, iter last, const T& val)

cdef void remove(vector[int] vect, int elem):
    vect.erase(std_remove[vector[int].iterator, int](vect.begin(), vect.end(), elem))

def blah():
    cdef vector[int] vect
    cdef int i
    for i in range(10):
        vect.push_back(i)
    for i in range(10):
        print vect[i]
        remove(vect, i)
    return vect
```

When I run `print blah()` I see:

```
0
1
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In other words the elements are not being removed from the vector. What simple mistake am I making?

Comment: For starters, it is spelled `std::remove`. Second, your `remove` declaration is different between your first and second code blocks - which definition are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry @nneonneo, I updated my code. I found the issues with the declaration (the `::` being one of them) but now the remove doesn't seem to be working as expected. The question now reflects that.

Comment: To answer your other question @nneonneo, I have defined a `std_remove` which gets called by my `remove` function that is suppose to actually `erase` the element from the vector.

Comment: When you modify `vect` in your `remove()` function, are you operating on a *reference* to `vect`, or are you operating on a *copy* of `vect`? If you want a *reference*, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721727/478288).

Comment: Thanks @chrisaycock, I just figured out that is what I was missing.

Comment: @BenMabey So you accepted an "answer" that didn't address your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing an element from a vector in C++ is extremely easy. Your erase/remove combo is [for more complicated stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Given an iterator `it`, then

```
v.erase(it)
```

will erase it (see the [pertinent `vector` doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)).

---

Incidentally, if you need to find this iterator, you can use `find` (from `algorithm`):

```
std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), value);
```

Consequently, to erase the first occurrence of `value`, you can use

```
v.erase(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), value));
```

---

P.S. This isn't really a Cython question at all. It's a C++ question which came up in the context of Cython. Please consider retagging. This will help you get attention for your question from relevant people.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out `find` and the erase/remove idiom. I was able to update my code to use find but the elements are still not being removed: https://gist.github.com/bmabey/6b2ea582fd4c8a463af9

Comment: Nevermind, I was missing a `&` of course. :)  Thanks again.